# Hash overriding a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, yaml

I got some yml config files with a deep, different structures and I want to extract passwords(that are located on different levels) and store them in a yml file outside a git repo. Let me show an example

`config1.yml`

```
a:
  b:
    c: 1
    password: secret
    ...
  d: 2
  ...
```

I wish to replace `secret` with `''` and extract a pass to a different yml file that will look like:

`config1_passwords.yml`

```
a:
  b:
    password: secret
```

Is there any way to merge `config1.yml` without passwords with `config1_passwords.yml` to get a correct config structure?

So basically in terms of hashes(parsed ymls) I want to do following:

```
{ :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :password => '' }, :d => 2 } }
{ :a => { :b => { :password => 'secret' } } } 
# =>
{ :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :password => 'secret' }, :d => 2 } }
```

Thanks for suggestions

**EDITED**
another example

```
{ :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :d => { :password1 => '' }, :password2 => '' } } }
{ :a => { :b => { :d => { :password => 'secret' }, :password2 => 'secret2' } } }
# =>
{ :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :d => { :password => 'secret' }, :password2 => 'secret2' } } }
```

Comment: with `{ :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :password => '' }, :d => 2 } }` and `{ :a => { :b => { :password => 'secret' } } } ` you want `{ :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :password => 'secret' }, :d => 2 } }`. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, but structure could be different, as well as there could be multiple passwords at different levels. Second hash would contain only the passwords, no matter how deep it is, so I need a universal solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3 has a [`deep_merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge), which does exactly what you want.

```
a = { :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :d => { :password1 => '' }, :password2 => '' } } }
b = { :a => { :b => { :d => { :password1 => 'secret' }, :password2 => 'secret2' } } }
a.deep_merge(b)
# -> {:a=> {:b=> {:c=>1, :d=>{:password1=>"secret"}, :password2=>"secret2"}}}
```

Note: I changed `a[:a][:b][:d]` to contain `:password1` instead of `:password`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this can be done using Ruby one-liners. But a simple recursive function might do

```
def recurse_merge_password! conf_hash, pw_hash
  pw_hash.keys.each do |k|
    next unless conf_hash.has_key?(k)
    case
      when k == :password
        conf_hash[:password] = pw_hash[:password]
      when conf_hash[k].is_a?(Hash) && pw_hash[k].is_a?(Hash)
        recurse_merge_password! conf_hash[k], pw_hash[k]
    end
  end
end

h1 = { :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :password => '' }, :d => 2 } }

h2 = { :a => { :b => { :password => "secret" } } }

recurse_merge_password! h1, h2

puts h1.inspect

=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1, :password=>"secret"}, :d=>2}}
```

If you have arrays and other structures that you may need to traverse, it is up to you to improve on this. Note I made it modify the config in place.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want some sort of Hash deep merge. It's available in [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) (part of Rails):

```
# You can omit this require statement if you're running Rails.
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge"

a = { a: { b: { c: 1, d: { password1: "" }, password2: "" } } }
b = { a: { b: { d: { password1: "secret" }, password2: "secret2" } } }

a.deep_merge(b)
#=> { a: { b: { c: 1, d: { password1: "secret"}, password2: "secret2" } } }
```

If you don't want to depend on ActiveSupport, take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb).